# How to redirect to a specific page from a JS displayed page in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have an asp.net application with master page. In one of the pages I have a button click event which opens another page using javascript as shown below.

```
string urlVerify = "VerifyEnrollmentEntries.aspx";
string fullURLVerify = "var newVerifyDataWindow = window.open('" + urlVerify +               "','_blank','height=600,width=950,status=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=no,titlebar=no' ); 
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page.GetType(), "OpenWindow", fullURLVerify, true);
```

This popup page doesn't have a master page. This is just a stand alone page, but part of the project. When the user clicks the close button on this popup page, I want to close this page and redirect to a specific page in the asp.net. Right now when the close button is clicked, the page closes and the parent page which caused the popup is shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before closing your popup, execute JS code:

```
opener.location.href = "YourRedirectUrl.aspx"
```

It will redirect parent to that URL